# Why having different version of IE is not triggered

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following script which checks for what version of IE I am running and use a stylesheet as well as show an alert statement:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = "<!--[if lte IE 9]><i></i><![endif]-->";
        var isIeLessThan9 = (div.getElementsByTagName("i").length == 1);
        if (isIeLessThan9) {
            alert("<=9");
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_ie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/captionStyle_ie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
        }
        if (!isIeLessThan9) {
            alert(">9");
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/captionStyle.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
        }
```

What's happening is for IE version 10 and higher it shows `>=10` and anything less than IE version 10 still shows `>=10`

How can I fix it?

***EDIT***:

This is the updated code which should fix the issue:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var isMobile = {
        Android: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function () {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        }
    };



    navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]:[navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
    return M.join(' ');
})();
var browserversion1 = navigator.sayswho.split(" ");
var browserversion2 = browserversion1[1].split(".")[0].split(",");
var isIeLessThan10 = browserversion1[0] == "IE" && browserversion2[0] < 10;




    if (!isMobile.any()) {
        if (isIeLessThan10) {
            alert("IE<10");
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_ie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/captionStyle_ie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
        }
        else {
            alert("IE>=10 || !IE");
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/captionStyle.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("mobile");
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_mobile.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/captionStyle_mobile.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
    }
</script>
```

Both IE8 and FF displays the alert, `IE>=10 || !IE`

Comment: If `getElementsByTagName` doesn't match any elements, I'd expect its `length` to be `0`, not `-1`.

Comment: What Anthony said.  If the returned `NodeList` is empty its length would be 0.

Comment: **Important** _As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode_. Read all about it here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX

Comment: @davidkonrad So how can I edit my code so if it's anything greater than or equal to IE 10 use the `defaultStyle.css` and if IE version less than 10 use `defaultStyle_ie.css`

Comment: @VolkanUlukut Just saw it. Thanks. Will check it out.

Comment: updated it, turns out first function wasn't working as expected. also added a JSFiddle with working example.

Comment: According to the docs `<!--[if lte IE 9]>` should do the trick. That is, targeting **any** IE below 10. `lte` stands for **less-than or equal**. So simply use that conditional comment. Why do you want to show an alert box and create an element?

Comment: I am using `alert` for testing and once I have it working correctly, it will be removed. I already did what you suggested but in IE 10 it still displays the LTE IE 10 stylesheet :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use this functions to get browser and its version rather than relying on html tag counts, which can easily change with your content: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsMy8/6/)

```
 navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]:[navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
    return M.join(' ');
})();
var browserversion1 = navigator.sayswho.split(" ");
var browserversion2 = browserversion1[1].split(".")[0].split(",");
var isIeLessThan10 = (browserversion1[0] == "IE" || browserversion1[0] == "MSIE") && browserversion2[0] < 10;
```

Comment: fixed the function, please check and cancel down-vote if it satisfies now.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Sorry. I will check the answer and accept if it works. Thanks

Comment: So, if it returns false, the browser is less then version 10? and if it's true, it is using browser greater than or equal to 10?

Comment: isIeLessThan10 is set to true if ie is less than 10 and false if browser is not ie or ie is greater than or equal to 10

Comment: Did not work. I updated my question with your code but it still is displaying the same message for IE 8 and FF and IE 10.

Comment: okay just found out another glitch. turns out IE is giving his name as MSIE in older versions. i'm updating the code above now and JSFiddle

Comment: Not sure who -1 your answer but I made it 0 :)